# Computing $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{\sin(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to compute

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{\sin(x)}.
$$

I've been trying to get it into a form where I can apply L'Hopital's rule, but I haven't had any success. Namely, I haven't been able to massage it into a fraction form. Any advice?

Comment: Alternatively write the taylor polynomial of this at $x = 1$. Then the conclusion also follows.

Comment: The function f(x)=e^sin(x) has a Taylor series centered at zero but this x^sin(x) looks much more difficult. I hope I'm wrong!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Using the L'Hopital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\sin x\ln x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln x}{\frac1{\sin x}}=-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sin(x) \log(x) = 0$. Hence,
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{\sin(x)} = 1$$

Comment: Is the first fact supposed to be evident, or is it an implied use of L'Hopital's to find the limit?

Comment: @Nasser $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \log(x) = -\infty$

Comment: @Nasser You tell me. What's $\lim \limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} x^2$?

Comment: @Nasser Bad example. I meant $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x^2} x$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14102/discussion-between-michael-t-and-nasser)

Comment: @MichaelT Yes, it is evident since as $x \to 0$, $\sin(x) \sim x$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \log(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$x^{\sin x}=e^{\ln x\sin x}$$
Then, apply l'Hopital's rule to 
$$\frac{\sin x}{1/\ln x}$$
Last, apply the continuity of exponential function.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{Result \; I}:$ If $x \in [0,\pi)$, then

$$ x^{\sin x} \leq \sin x(x - 1 ) + 1  $$

To see why this is true, notice that $x \in [0, \pi) $ implies that $\sin x \geq 0 $, hence invoking the Young's Inequality and the fact that $\sin x + (1 - \sin x) = 1$, we have

$$ x^{\sin x} = x^{\sin x}\cdot1^{1- \sin x} \leq \sin x \cdot x + 1 - \sin x = \sin x(x -1 ) + 1 $$

$\mathbf{Result \; II}$: $$x^{\sin x} \geq 1 - 10 x $$

You should try to show this inequality: You can find the min of $f(x) = x^{ \sin x} + 10 x $.

Now,

$$ \sin x(x -1) + 1 \geq x^{\sin x} \geq 1 - 10 x $$

Hence, an application of of the squeeze rule gives that

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{\sin x} = 1 $$

Comment: Jeez, talk about a sledgehammer for a molehill!